# Exporting TaskID of ECS Fargate container and use it later point in AWS CDK code

Tags: typescript, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am using CDK version 2 with typescript, I have a scenario where I want the value of TaskID from ECS Fargate Container to be part of another command. I am using `new ecs.Cluster` and `new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition` to create the stack. Can someone tell me how I can export the value to use it later in code.

Comment: Please share a (minimum) version of the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because a task ID is not a static value. Tasks are launched (often more than one) and stopped, restarted, etc. The task ID changes all the time. You will not be able to get a single task ID from an ECS service in a reasonable way.